# Python "for item not in list" not working correctly

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am working on a facial recognition project and me and my mates have been stuck on an absurdly simple problem since yesterday. Having run out of possible solutions, I have come to you for help.

The basic code is as follows:

```
list=[]
while true:
    nbr_predicted, conf = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
    if nbr_predicted not in list:
        list.append(nbr_predicted)
```

Here `nbr_predicted` is an integer which corresponds to the id of the predicted person and conf is the confidence of the prediction.
Let us assume that we are using a single picture for multiple predictions. The code should supposedly insert on the first iteration, and then skip further insertions. However, the code simply attempts to insert the same id again even on further iterations. I have a hunch it is due the returning value of the function `recognizer.predict()` but I am unable to pinpoint it.
I've left out some of the finer details which I believe is not related to the problem at hand.

Just in case, I will leave the full code below.

```
import cv2,os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image 
import pickle
import MySQLdb
import datetime
from random import randint
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",    
                     user="######",
                     passwd="######",  
                     db="######")

recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
recognizer.read('trainer/trainer.yml')
cascadePath = "Classifiers/face.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascadePath);
path = 'dataSet'

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
while True:
    inp = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if inp == ord('q'):        
        #cam.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
    #ret, im =cam.read()
    im = cv2.imread('D:\Images\pic.jpg')
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces=faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.2, minNeighbors=5, minSize=(100, 100), flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)
    list=[]
    for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
        nbr_predicted, conf = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
        cv2.rectangle(im,(x-50,y-50),(x+w+50,y+h+50),(225,0,0),2)
        print(nbr_predicted)
        print(conf)
        if(conf>45):
            nbr_predicted_person='UNKNOWN'
        cursor = db.cursor()
        if not nbr_predicted in list:        
            print("Insertion started")
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO attendence VALUES (%s, %s, %s,%s,%s)",
                           (randint(0, 90),152134,None,datetime.datetime.now(),5))
            print("Insertion finished")
            list.append(nbr_predicted)
            db.commit()
            db.close()
            print(list)
        cv2.putText(im,str(nbr_predicted),(x,y+h),font,2,(255,0,0),2,cv2.LINE_AA)#Draw the text
        cv2.imshow('im',im)
        cv2.waitKey(10)
```

Please note that this is not the final code and we are still in the process of debugging and adding additional functions. Any help is much appreciated.

Here is an additional pic of the code not working:

[image]

The first insertion goes fine, the list indicates that the id has been inserted, but on the next iteration, even though the predicted id is already in list, the insertion still starts. The error occurs because of false insertion in the database, but that is beyond the point. It shouldn't even start the insertion.

Comment: `list` is a type name in Python, bad idea to overwrite it with your own data.

Comment: *However, that is not the case when I run it*.  **Well** what happens instead?

Comment: What do you mean "Not working correctly"?

Comment: From your title : `for item not in list` indeed doesn't work.

Comment: @Adelin pics added :D

Comment: @SkyFire dont post pics, copy-paste text in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, as I thought, absurdly simple. We(and by 'we' I mean a mate of mine), declared the list INSIDE the while loop instead of outside. Causing it to create a new list every iteration.

Comment: Its shameful it took as long as it did to debug this. Any debugging tips are appreciated.